# Timeout while Internet Explorer busy

Tags: internet-explorer, nunit, cruisecontrol.net, watin

During execution of tests on ccnet server. Some of the tests fails saying Timeout while Internet Explorer busy and hangs the system and at the end show the old results-xml file in nunit results even I am using a clean build.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue with WatiN-tests. I can't write text to a TextField. I have no idea for how to solve it yet.

**Update:** I downgraded from IE8 to IE6 and ran the WatiN-tests again without the timeout issue.

Comment: @Ola I am having the same issue, but I haven't downgraded IE again